# Can a CNAME DNS record point to a subdirectory

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Can a DNS record point to an address like my.domain.com/subdir1

Answer (score 60, accepted):

DNS records only map IP addresses to hostnames so in a word, no

You could, however, use a hostname configuration in your web server to serve a subdirectory when a request comes in.  Like having something.domain.com redirect/equate to somethingelse.domain.com/downhere.  That would depend on your web server software, not DNS.

Comment: Thanks, so for Apache I can edit the apache2.conf file I assume

Comment: In apache, specifically, you would use the VirtualHosts feature.

Answer (score 23):

CNAME records are part of the Domain Name System, the naming system for the internet. Their only purpose is to translate host names, like `www.example.com` into IP addresses. You can't attach folder names or queries to a CNAME. To be precise, CNAME resolve into other names, which themselves can be A-Records pointing to IP addresses or other CNAME records.

Your example `my.domain.com/subdir1` or better `http://my.domain.com/subdir1` A URI, a Uniform Resource Identifier which is used todentify or name a resource on the Internet - in your case a HTTP resource.

So, a workaround could be to define a CNAME to a different host header, which redirects to your folder using the [HTTP status response 301 ("moved permanently")](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

```
-> Browser requests subdir1.domain.com 
-> Server sends a HTTP status code 301 to the browser:
   REDIRECT my.domain.com/subdir1
```

All web servers and web programming languages provide commands for these types of redirects.

Answer (score 8):

What you're asking for is a URL redirect.  A CNAME record will NOT accomplish this.

Your easiest bet would probably be to either use an .htaccess file or (even easier) just write a quick web page with a meta refresh or a javascript redirect to automatically redirect the user.

You didn't mention your OS or web server so I'm just trying to provide the best generic answer I can.

Comment: what about with github pages?

Answer (score 4):

No. CNAME records can only point to DNS records. You're looking for a HTTP redirect.