# Setup custom domain with folder in path for Blogger hosted blog

Tags: domain, directory

Google Blogger makes it easy to put a blog at a [custom top-level domain or custom subdomain](http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1233381&page=ts.cs), such as:

> ```
> www.example.com
> blog.example.com
> ```

The setup involves creating a CNAME pointing to:

> ```
> ghs.google.com
> ```

How do you setup a blog to be on a custom domain with a folder name in the URL path?

Example blog home:

> ```
> www.example.com/blog
> ```

A [CNAME won't work](https://serverfault.com/questions/47175/can-a-cname-dns-record-point-to-a-subdirectory) because that's at the DNS level not the HTTP level.  A redirect will alter the URL in the user's browser, so that won't do either.

Is there a simple way to do this?  (Note: My registrar is Namecheap and my site is running Apache/2.2.16 with cPanel on a unix server at Umbra Hosting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, the answer appears to be **no**.

**Blogger Settings**
[image: Blogger Settings]

It looks like there is no way to *"setup a blog to be on a custom domain with a folder name in the URL path"*, such as:

```
www.example.com/blog
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 ways to do it.

### Method #1: Using a "meta" tag

You could just stick a `index.html` file at the top of **www.example.com** that redirects to **www.example.com/blog**. This `index.html` file would make use of the "meta" tags that are available in the `<head>` tag:

#### For example

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.example.com/blog/">
  <title>www.example.com blog</title>
</head>

<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

You can read more about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh).

**NOTE:** This method requires that you only want www.example.com/index.html to redirect to www.example.com/blog/.

### Method #2: Using an Apache rewrite

```
#-- blog.example.com --#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  UseCanonicalName Off
  RewriteEngine On

  ServerName blog.example.com

  # blog 
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

### Method #3: Using an Apache Reverse Proxy

If you're attempting to take traffic in on say URL http://www.example.com/blog/ but your actual blog is at http://mysuperblog.blogger.com/, then another option would be to reverse proxy the mysuperblog.blogger.com behind an Apache instance tasked with sitting out in front.

```
#-- www.example.com/blog --#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  UseCanonicalName Off
  RewriteEngine On

  ServerName www.example.com

  # /blog -> /blog/
  RewriteRule ^/blog$ /blog/ [R]

  # blog
  ProxyPass /blog http://mysuperblog.blogger.com
  ProxyPassReverse /blog http://mysuperblog.blogger.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**NOTE:** In order to make use of Apache's reverse proxy functionality make sure that you enable the mod_proxy module.

Comment: The blog should end up on `/blog`, but the main site (not the blog) still needs to be at the root level.  Additionally, a meta refresh would not cause the actual blog to appear at `/blog`.

Comment: OK, you did not mention any of that in the question, you might want to update the question to reflect your more specific needs.

Comment: The updated Method #2 seems a bit closer as it does not redirect the website root.  Like Method #1, however, it looks like it points the browser to `/blog` but there won't be anything there (nonetheless, I gave the VirtualHost a try... encountered a 500 server error).  What would cause the blog (hosted on Google Blogger) to show up at `/blog`?

Comment: I think I understand what you're looking for finally. You want to present the site as www.example.com/blog even though it might be getting served from just blah.blogger.com (or whatever), correct?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to setup a blog to be on a custom domain with a folder name in the URL path.  For example: `www.example.com/blog`